# How can I suppress Print in parallel evaluation?

Tags: programming, parallelization

When using a function that includes `Print` statements, one can suppress the output by

`Print; Unprotect[Print]; Print = Null &`

This doesn't work when the function is evaluated in

`ParallelTable[function[i],{i,1,10}]`

Is there a way to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried executing the redefinition of Print in all the kernels you are using for evaluation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use dynamic scoping, i.e. the Block construct, to temporarily "forget" or redefine Print.

```
ParallelTable[
Block[{Print},
Print; Unprotect[Print]; Print = Null &
function[x],
{x,0,10}
]
```

This works with ParallelTable for me.

Comment: works! thank you.

Comment: What about `Block[{Print = Null&}, ...]`? That doesn't even need an `Unprotect`.

Comment: I would find it unusual if this worked, because the definition of `Print` is not synchronized across kernels, and indeed it does not work here.  I tried `Block[{}, Print; Unprotect[Print]; Print = Null &; 
 ParallelDo[Print[i], {i, 1, 10}]]` which is completely analogous with your example, yet it does print the output.  Furthermore, in your example the modification of `Print` is *not* temporary.

Comment: As I said, it works for me. *Including* temporary modification. Why it works, may be a different question.

Comment: @noe Try in a fresh kernel.  If you use the exact same code that you posted, the modification cannot be temporary, because you didn't pass `Print` to `Block` in the first argument.  Then there's the question of synchronization between subkernels.

Comment: The only way I can see this working is if you put this code inside `ParallelTable`, but even then you will change the definition of `Print` permanently for the parallel kernels. Try for example running `ParallelDo[Print[i], {i,10}]` afterwards. A safer option would be to do something like `ParallelTable[Block[{Print}, Print = Null &;...], ...]`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, but I did indeed put the Block within ParallelTable, i.e. ran  `ParallelTable[Block[..]]`.

Comment: @noe If you put the `Block` inside `ParallelTable` then in fact `Block` had no effect.  Dynamic scoping was not used.  What happens is that `Print` is redefined *permanently* in all the subkernels, but not in the main kernel.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
ParallelDo[Block[{Print = Null&}, Print[{i, $KernelID}]], {i,1,10}]
```

You can also make it into a function:

```
SetAttributes[ParallelDoSilent, HoldAll]
ParallelDoSilent[expr_, iter_] :=
  ParallelDo[Block[{Print = Null&}, expr], iter]

ParallelDoSilent[Print[{i, $KernelID}], {i,1,10}]
```

Comment: +1, yes, this is the correct and general solution.  This is good reading on `Block` (for the OP): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661393/mathematica-module-versus-with-or-block-guideline-rule-of-thumb-for-usage  `With` is not going to act *inside* functions, and permanently redefining `Print` is error-prone and inconvenient.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for pointing out some of the subtle properties of `Block`

Comment: How do I revert this? If I want to have `Print` work again as usual in the current Mathematica session?

Comment: @becko: As soon as the `Block` finishes execution, `Print` is automatically reverted to the previous value (which should be the original `Print` function, unless you did any further change to it outside the `Block`). If you want to re-enable `Print` while still inside the `Block`, just use `Print =.` to undo the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work for me.

```
ParallelEvaluate[Unprotect@Print];
ParallelEvaluate[Print = Null &];
ParallelDo[Print[{i, $KernelID}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

This also seemed to work:

```
ParallelDo[With[{Print = Null &}, Print[{i, $KernelID}]], {i, 1, 10}]
```